# facing issue in method channel internet connectivity in unit testing in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, connectivity

I have checked internet connectivity in flutter while calling api in store class like this using 'connectivity' library.

```
    Future<bool> callApi() async {

    final isInternet = await Util.checkInternetAndShowDialog(context);

    if (isInternet) {

      final future = _repository.callApi();

      var res = await future;

      return true;

    }

return false;

    }
```

In Util class network connectivity is been checked like this::

```
class Util {

  static Future<bool> checkInternetAndShowDialog(BuildContext context) async{
    var internet = await NetworkConnectivity.rechability();
    if (internet == false) {
      AlertMessage().showAlertDialog(context, 'error message');
    }
    return internet;
  }

}
```

In NetworkConnectivity class network connectivity is been checked using Connectivity library.

```
class NetworkConnectivity {

static Future<bool> rechability() async {

    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());

    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {

      return true;

    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {

      return true;

    }

    return false;

  }

}
```

my test cases code is like below:

```
test('call api successfully', () async {

      when(mockStore.callApi()).thenAnswer((realInvocation) => Future.value());
      expect(await store.callApi(), true);
    });
```

so while writing unit testing I am facing error of connectivity and method channel.
[connectivity error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wEjN.png)

Can any one help please me how I can mock for internet connectivity in unit testing and pass the test in flutter. I shall be thankful for this.